# É possível extrair o header de uma DLL? Se sim, como?

Tags: dll, header

É possível extrair `header` de uma `dll`? Essa prática é possível? Se sim, como posso fazer?

Comment: Por header você quer dizer a assinatura dos métodos? Metadata? Ou detalhes como o nome da aplicação?

Comment: Isso, as assinaturas dos métodos. Mas quanto mais informações forem possíveis extrair, melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Caso esteja usando C#, utilize a classe `FileVersionInfo`:

```
myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("dll-alvo.dll");
```

As propriedades da instância expõem os detalhes de compilação - por exemplo `CompanyName`, `ProductName` e `ProductVersion`.

Para extrair as classes de um dado *assembly*, você precisará usar *reflection*:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("dll-alvo.dll");

foreach (Type tc in assembly .GetTypes())
{
    Console.WriteLine(tc.FullName);
}
```

E finalmente listando todos os métodos de uma dada classe:

```
    foreach (Type tc in assembly .GetTypes())
        {
            if (tc.IsAbstract)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Abstract Class : " + tc.Name);
            }
            else if (tc.IsPublic)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Public Class : " + tc.Name);
            }
            else if (tc.IsSealed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sealed Class : " + tc.Name);
            }  

            //Obtém lista de nomes de métodos
            MemberInfo[] methodName = tc.GetMethods();

            foreach (MemberInfo method in methodName)
            {
                if (method.ReflectedType.IsPublic)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Método público : " + method.Name.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Método não público : " + method.Name.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Fontes: [1](http://www.venkateswarlu.co.in/dotnet/Get_all_methods_from_a_class.aspx), [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.aspx).

Comment: Então @lbotinelly, eu tentei usar o seu exemplo de `reflection` mas não deu certo, ao tentar carregar uma `dll` para exemplo, a seguinte mensagem apareceu: ***An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll***  . O comando que usei foi: ` Assembly assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("C:\\Users\\Eduardo\\Desktop\\winusb.dll");`